# How write to json file the time when the Scrapy spider has finished scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-pipeline

How an example code on how to record into the json file the time when the Scrapy spider/crawler stops (completes) collecting the data. Example code below:

**Example CrawlSpider:**

```
from scrapy.http import request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from ebaycomp.items import EbayItem


class EbaySpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'spider'
    allowed_domains = ['ebay.co.uk']

    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/49831/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=chain+and+sprocket+kit&LH_ItemCondition=1000&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=1',
                  'https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/177771/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=motorcycle+air+filter&LH_ItemCondition=1000&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=1']

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('.*'),
                                restrict_xpaths=(['//a[@class="s-item__link"][1]',
                                                  '//a[@class="s-item__link"][2]',
                                                  '//a[@class="s-item__link"][3]'
                                                  ])), callback='parse_items', follow=True)]

    def parse_items(self, response):

        scrapedItem = EbayItem()
        scrapedItem['startUrl'] = 'how to properly return the start_url?'
        scrapedItem['productUrl'] = 'how to properly return the 3 product urls?'
        scrapedItem['productTitle'] = response.xpath('//h1/text()').get()
        scrapedItem['productPrice'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="price"]/text()').get()
        scrapedItem['timeClosed'] = 'the time the spider has stopped'

        return scrapedItem
```

**Here's my json pipeline (not sure how to extract time and feed into json output):**

```
class JsonWriterPipeline:

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.file = open('ebay_out.jl', 'w')

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, productItem, spider):
    line = json.dumps(ItemAdapter(productItem).asdict()) + "\n"
    self.file.write(line)
    return productItem
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read again the documentation, specificaly about crawlers.

1. Scrapy will follow your rules for each url in start_urls.
2. When you get to the parse_item you're already in the product page, so if you want to get the url it's just 'response.url'.

If you want to limit your CrawlSpider then you can set:

```
custom_settings = (
        {
            'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': whatever number you want,
            'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1,
        }
    )
# also you can just leave restrict_xpaths=(['//a[@class="s-item__link"'],]) and lose the rest.
```

(More information [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#module-scrapy.extensions.closespider)).

3. If you want json then why do you write it to csv?
4. There's an [example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file) in the scrapy documentation on writing items to a json file.
5. In this case I think it's better to use scrapy.Spider.

Comment: I am writing to csv because it's easier to just open and inspect the results. I don't see why it's better to use scrapy.Spider and an answer to how to write spider close time to json output.

Comment: write to close time with pipeline

Comment: I don't think this answers my questions (particularly about the start_urls and productUrl) being returned in the response and stored in a tidy manner. I don't see a justification for using scrapy.Spider over CrawlSpider. Also, I need some example code for the json Pipeline + timestamp.